# Connecting postgres DB with heroku

Tags: django, heroku-postgres

During development, I used postgres DB where I had to pip install psycopg2. Most of my post I updated during the course of development was on postgres DB. Now during deployment, I discovered that a part of the installation when I did heroku push master is installing sqlite. Now my problem is, how can I deploy my postgres DB for development in heroku, knowing that most of my post on development are really important.. thanks

Comment: did you follow these instructions to get a postgres instance up and running on Heroku? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres

Comment: @ja408, Thanks for the link, I'll go through it and see for myself.   But just for the record, I used postgres DB for my development, how can I update my data on the postgres DB for development into the deployment stage

Comment: Django has a great command line utility to get data out of one db into another.  `python manage.py dumpdata -o <file_name>.json` and into the new database with loaddata, i.e. `python manage.py loaddata <file_name>.json`.